# How to wrap line at some characters other than space?

Tags: wrapping

How to set Emacs to wrap long line (using Visual Line Mode) at `-`, `_`, `(`, `)` too, instead of just at spaces.

A sample line:

This is a long line with long words like long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-word, long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_long_word, (very)long(very)long(very)long(very)long(very)long(very)long(very)long(very)long(very)long(very)long(very)long-word.

Comment: please accept @dlukes answer to give others the opportunity to see a solution :)

Answer (score 5):

[As of Emacs 28.1](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/emacs/news/NEWS.28.1), this is now possible by setting `word-wrap-by-category` to `t` and customizing the categories of the relevant characters as detailed in [Drew's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19029).

You can either do this globally:

```lisp
(setq word-wrap-by-category t)
;; Add the | (= line-breakable) category to the - char.
(modify-category-entry ?- ?| (standard-category-table))
```

Or on a buffer-local basis with a hook (e.g. for all Org Mode buffers):

```lisp
(setq my-category-table (copy-category-table))
(modify-category-entry ?- ?| my-category-table)
(defun my-soft-wrap-hook ()
  (set-category-table my-category-table)
  (setq-local word-wrap-by-category t)
  ;; Presumably, you also want to enable visual-line-mode
  ;; or visual-fill-column-mode as part of this hook?
  (visual-line-mode))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my-soft-wrap-hook)
```

The latter might be more desirable if you use soft-wrapping in some modes (e.g. Org Mode) but hard-wrapping in others (e.g. programming modes), because modifying character categories also affects hard-wrapping (its original purpose), and you probably don't want `a-long-elisp-variable-name` to be split into multiple lines on `-` when applying hard-wrapping.

Here's a screenshot demonstrating how it works on your first example line:

[image: screenshot demonstrating line breaks at -]

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source code, it doesn't seem to be possible, as the definition of white-space relevant for `visual-line-mode` appears to be hard-coded in the C part of the source code.

I'm not sure about my conclusions, but here is the sequence of my source archaeology (I'll be linking to github for ease of reference, though when actually carrying out the investigation I had used `C-h f`, `C-h v` and finally a recursive `grep` of the C code.)

`visual-line-mode` enables word-wrap by [setting the variable `word-wrap` to `t`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/7a2038d7c887e4fa08a91950a7494d1dd20c39e1/lisp/simple.el#L6805). (You can test this by just setting the variable to true, without enabling `visual-line-mode` itself.)

The variable `word-wrap` is defined in [buffer.c](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/7a2038d7c887e4fa08a91950a7494d1dd20c39e1/src/buffer.c#L5614):

```
DEFVAR_PER_BUFFER ("word-wrap", &BVAR (current_buffer, word_wrap), Qnil,
[...]
```

Guessing (and my terminology will be off, because I'm a horrible person who hasn't yet read all of the texinfo manual), this means that the elisp-accessible variable "word-wrap", sets the C variable `word_wrap`.

Searching for where `word_wrap` is used, [we find](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/7a2038d7c887e4fa08a91950a7494d1dd20c39e1/src/xdisp.c#L2840):

```
it->line_wrap = NILP (BVAR (current_buffer, word_wrap))
  ? WINDOW_WRAP : WORD_WRAP;
```

i.e. if `word_wrap` is set in the current buffer, the `it->line_wrap` is set to `WORD_WRAP` (`A ? B : C` is a ternary operator...).

Looking further on, we get, among other things, [this condition](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/7a2038d7c887e4fa08a91950a7494d1dd20c39e1/src/xdisp.c#L8723):

```
  if (it->line_wrap == WORD_WRAP && it->area == TEXT_AREA)
    {
      if (IT_DISPLAYING_WHITESPACE (it))
          may_wrap = true;
    [...]
```

I'm eliding quite a large amount of code, which I don't really, fully understand, but it seems that unless `IT_DISPLAYING_WHITESPACE (it)` then either `may_wrap` will be explicitly set to false, or we'll escape the block and do something interesting elsewhere.

`IT_DISPLAYING_WHITESPACE` in turn, is defined [here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/7a2038d7c887e4fa08a91950a7494d1dd20c39e1/src/xdisp.c#L353):

```
#define IT_DISPLAYING_WHITESPACE(it)                    \
  ((it->what == IT_CHARACTER && (it->c == ' ' || it->c == '\t'))    \
   || ((STRINGP (it->string)                        \
    && (SREF (it->string, IT_STRING_BYTEPOS (*it)) == ' '       \
        || SREF (it->string, IT_STRING_BYTEPOS (*it)) == '\t')) \
       || (it->s                            \
       && (it->s[IT_BYTEPOS (*it)] == ' '               \
           || it->s[IT_BYTEPOS (*it)] == '\t'))         \
       || (IT_BYTEPOS (*it) < ZV_BYTE                   \
       && (*BYTE_POS_ADDR (IT_BYTEPOS (*it)) == ' '         \
|| *BYTE_POS_ADDR (IT_BYTEPOS (*it)) == '\t')))) \
```

suggesting that the only two recognised white-space characters are the space and the tab.

Hence, it appears that tabs and spaces are hard-coded as the only characters at which wrapping is allowed to occur, but as already written above, I might (hopefully) be wrong.

Comment: It seems that I was unfortunately correct: [see this comment by Eli Zaretskii](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=13399#8) in a very interesting bug thread dedicated to trying to fix this.

There seems to be an attempt at a fix [here](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=13399#113), but apparently it doesn't work and there hasn't been any recent progress.

(I'm not sure if I'm up to dealing with something like this properly...)

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need to do (e.g., in the mode where you will be filling text):

```el
(modify-category-entry ?- ?|)
```

That gives the hyphen character (`-`) the category of `|`, which means ***line breakable***.  Do the same for `_`, `(`, and `)`, if you want lines to be broken at each of those characters also. (But I suspect that you do not really want lines to be broken after `(` -- just after `)`.)

You can use `M-x describe-categories` to see the available categories.

(I should say that I did not bother to try this with `visual-line-mode` (I don't use or like `visual-line-mode`), but only with ordinary text filling.  If `(modify-category-entry ?- ?|)` is not sufficient for `visual-line-mode` then you might need to tinker a bit more with it or perhaps look at the `visual-line-mode` code to see how it does filling (if it is different from the usual filling).)

---

How I found this out:

1. I looked at the code that does filling.  I started with just command `fill-paragraph` (bound to `M-q`), and I eventually got to function `fill-move-to-break-point`.
2. Function `fill-move-to-break-point` does this:

```el
    (re-search-backward "[ \t]\\|\\c|.\\|.\\c|" linebeg 0)`
```

3. Not being familiar with `\c`, I looked in the Elisp manual, under regexps, node [Regexp Backslash](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html), and saw that "`\cC` matches any character whose category is `C`.".  I followed the link there to node [Categories](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Categories.html).
4. I knew nothing about categories at this point, although I had some familiarity with character tables.  So I read about categories.
5. I found, from `M-x describe-categories` and from the `fill-move-to-break-point` code, that `|` is the category for a character to be *line breakable*.
   So I tried modifying the category entry for the character `-` (hyphen) to be *line-breakable* (`|`).  It worked.

Comment: It doesn't work with either `visual-line-mode` on (still wrap at spaces) or off (still wrap at window edge).

Comment: @aggu Drew said **in the mode where you will be filling text** so you have to enable `auto-fill-mode` and/or use `fill-paragraph` (`M-q`).